# using pyspark can I write to s3 path I don't have GetObject permission to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

After spark finishes writing the dataframe to S3, it seems like it checks the validity of the files it wrote with: `getFileStatus` that is `HeadObject` behind the scenes.

What if I'm only granted write and list objects permissions but not GetObject?
Is there any way instructing pyspark on databricks to not do this validity test after a successful write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the S3A connector the answer is "no". It's not just about writing the file, it is about creating directories and committing work safely.

"being able to read what you have just written" is an expected behaviour of filesystems and the Hadoop cloud connectors offer that semantics so code doesn't break.

Comment: I wish there was, like with boto3, I can write a file with just `PutObject` and no `GetObject`, it's a shame there is no flag to opt-out. But yeah, seems like there is no way indeed. Got the same answer from 2 databricks employees. :(

Comment: well, it's that way to try and preserve the semantics of a filesystem. sorry. all the source is there if you want to disable the probes, or better return something fake

Comment: It's a PITA, but not big enough for me to fork bloody hadoop\spark :)

Comment: good move. You'd come to regret it in future.